# Retrive data from mongo collection collection.find(query)

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to find users from collections whose creation time are in the range of fromTime and toTime. 
user collection is

```
db.users.find().limit(1).pretty() {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c51a42efeb366379f27c679"),
    "devices": [{
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
    ],
    "creationDate": NumberLong("1548854318313"),
    "isActive": true,
     ...
     ...
}
```

If I use findOne without any query, it works

```
DBCollection collection = getDB().getCollection(“users”);
System.out.println(“find One= " +    collection.findOne( ));
```

but when I am trying to add query then it is displaying no result.

```
DBCollection collection = getDB().getCollection(“users”);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(queryParams);
query.put(“creationDate”, BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromTime).add("$lte", toTime).get());
System.out.println(“collection.find(query));
```

where
fromTime=1548854318310  and  toTime= 1548854318315

It gives

```
DBCursor{collection=DBCollection{database=DB{name='appdb'}, name='users'},
find=FindOptions{, batchSize=0, limit=0, modifiers=null, projection=null, maxTimeMS=0, skip=0,
 sort=null, cursorType=NonTailable, noCursorTimeout=false, oplogReplay=false, partial=false}}
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *where fromTime=1548854318310 and toTime= 1548854318315* are you sure you have data within this 5 millisecond range?

Answer (score 0):

```
users.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"), //any date / time
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z") // any date / time
    }
})
=> { "_id" : ObjectId("4c0791e2b9ec877893f3363b"), "name" : "example", "created_at" : "Sun May 30 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)" } 
 //answer betweeen that date/time
```